# A toolbar for MathJax commands would be helpful

Tags: feature-request, editing, mathjax

As I was just writing my answer, I felt the need for the in-built MathJax toolbar for ease in writing equations and formulas without adding commands like \pi R^2 inside double $s. It will just create smooth writing experience for all, particularly the new ones.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13349/44126), and links therein. It’s a non-trivial problem.

Comment: I can’t find an answer of yours with any MathJax. Are you saying that you would use it if it were easier?

Comment: All I am saying is that a MathJax command toolbar is suggested for ease.

Comment: Minor historical note: the first MathJax-bearing content by the asker appeared sometime after the comment by @G.Smith. It’s a valid concern, because new users and experienced users frequently have different expectations of what software should do; this is discussed more extensively [at the related post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13349/44126).