# Is it possible to have the editor and preview in a side by side mode? Or maybe just a scrollbar in the preview?

Tags: feature-request, editing, mathjax

I have a question about my Physics Stack Exchange post: [A new way to define matrix-vector products, to relate physical fundamental constants and units of measure](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/693654/a-new-way-to-define-matrix-vector-products-to-relate-physical-fundamental-const)

I'm trying to convert my post to MathJax, but since it's a long post, I cannot ["see what I get"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG), while writing those complex MathJax expressions "blindly" does not help...

Having the editor side by side with the preview would be better to me, while just adding a scrollbar to the preview too (only the editor has one) would still work and would require very small changes in the Stack Exchange UI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Almost certainly not; changing the editor is a network-wide change which requires a *lot* of investment in usability testing across multiple browsers and platforms..

See [previously](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13349/44126), [previously](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13488/44126). You might use [the sandbox](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/389/44126) or [StackEdit.io](https://stackedit.io/).

Comment: I'll definitively go for StackEdit.io, thank you very much.

Comment: By the way... as a software engineer, IMHO, I'd expect such a complex and modern platform having been developed with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_design

This implies there will be one class(-set) for the editor and one for the preview, only the latter has to be changed to accommodate the scrolling feature, which is not big work (few hours).

In such a situation, with one change in one class all stack-exchange communities would benefit from that.

Comment: @ccampisano It's a large complex system, although there is a lot of work going into streamlining it. Don't forget, the initial software was created before Stack Overflow existed. ;) See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10369/334566 & https://stackoverflow.design/

Comment: Questions about side by side preview on the mother meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmarkdown-preview%5D+side+by+side